# Displaying separate items in a listbox from a collection

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm making a shopping basket winforms app that will take input from the user, who will specify a product name, a price and a quantity.

I have a dll with some methods relating to the app and a constructor that creates a list - I have instantiated this in my winforms code.

The issue I am having is that I am unable to separate different products in the listbox, it would replace the previous item the user entered e.g. it currently would read:

```
Product     Price      Quantity
Bread       3.60       3
Milk        6.57       5
Eggs        8.97       7
Bread       11.37      9
```

Where I would like it to read:

```
Product     Price      Quantity
Bread       6.00       5
Milk        1.19       2
Eggs        1.50       2
```

I would like it to show each item separately, with it's corresponding price and current quantity.

I have tried using a `foreach` loop to iterate through the basket but I get an error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'namespace.ShoppingBasket' because 'namespace.ShoppingBasket' does not
>   contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Should I be using an interface to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ShoppingBasket` class does not implement interface [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is required if you want to enumerate basket in `foreach`. If you don't want to implement that interface from scratch you can inherit from some class which already implements it (e.g. `List<T>`).

E.g. if you store order items in a list, you can return it's enumerator:

```
public class ShoppingBasket : IEnumerable<OrderItem>
{
    private List<OrderItem> items = new List<OrderItem>();

    // ...

    public IEnumerator<OrderItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

NOTE: You also can just add `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` method instead of implementing `IEnumerable` interface. That also will make `foreach` work.

Comment: I don't have huge experience with interfaces, I know how to implement it, but what should I put in place of `throw new NotImplementedException();` Thank you!

Comment: @RayB151 that depends on your ShoppingBasket class implementation. Can you show it?

Comment: Hope I understand correctly, is it this you mean? `IEnumerator<OrderItem> IEnumerable<OrderItem>.GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @RayB151 sorry, don't know what your code means, but if you want to treat your basket as sequence of order items it should implement `IEnumerable<OrderItem>` (which means implementing GetEnumerator method)

Comment: I have tried adding in the code you mentioned in your comment and I'm getting two errors regarding not having a public definition for GetEnumerator and it not having the matching return type of Systems.Collections.IEnumerator.

Comment: @RayB151 sorry, code above should work without errors. Make sure you have added exactly same code

Comment: I definitely added the same code, but amended the name of the list to match mine and added `<OrderItem>` in front of the `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @RayB151 I already provided `OrderItem` parameter for interface. You should not amend anything

Comment: I changed it back, but I had errors requesting a type, so I added the `System.Collections` it recommended me to add in front, it now works, but the product names have been replaced with `namespace.OrderItem`

Comment: @RayB151 that is what `ToString()` method returns by default. You have to set DisplayMember for listbox or override `ToString` of order item

Comment: I tried using `listBox1.DisplayMember = ProductName;` (If that's how that is done? I put it in my `foreach`, it didn't work so I tried outside but to no avail) But no luck, I'm not sure how to override the `ToString` of order item.

Comment: @RayB151 it should be `listBox1.DisplayMember = "ProductName";` and you should specify it before assigning data source for your listbox

Comment: That does work! I do have some issues still to fix but that's done, thanks very much! :)